# Compute the area of the image S under the mapping $x \mapsto Ax$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, cross-product

Let $S$ be the parallelogram determined by the vectors :
$b_1 = (-3,4), b_2 = (-3,8)$ and,

$A =
\begin{bmatrix}
    6 & -8 \\
    -2 & 8 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$

Compute the image $S$ under the mapping $x \mapsto Ax$

I don't really care for the answer I just want to know the mechanics and how to do the arithmetic. I have no clue.

Comment: What have you tried? Computing the images of $b_1$ and $b_2$ under $A$ seems like a first step. Or maybe you know something about the relationship between area and the determinant.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that the norm of the cross product gives the area spanned by two vectors (which in general will be a parallelogram).  The vectors $b_1$ and $b_2$ get mapped to the vectors:

$$
Ab_1 \;\; =\;\; \begin{bmatrix}
    6 & -8 \\
    -2 & 8 \\
    \end{bmatrix} \left [ \begin{array}{c}
-3\\ 4\\
\end{array} \right ] \;\; =\;\; \left [ \begin{array}{c}
-50 \\ 38 \\
\end{array} \right ]
$$
and
$$
Ab_2 \;\; =\;\; \begin{bmatrix}
    6 & -8 \\
    -2 & 8 \\
    \end{bmatrix} \left [\begin{array}{c}
-3 \\ 8 \\
\end{array} \right ] \;\; =\;\;  \left [\begin{array}{c}
-82 \\ 70 \\
\end{array} \right ].
$$

The area of these can easily be found by arranging them as the columns of a new matrix and taking their determinant:

$$
\text{Area} \;\; =\;\; \left |\det \left [ \begin{array}{cc}
-50 & -82 \\
38 & 70 \\
\end{array} \right ] \right | \;\; =\;\; |-3500 + 2624| \;\; =\;\; 876.
$$

Another way of seeing this is by recalling that the formula for the area of a parallelogram is base x height, which is equivalent to the quantity $||b_1||\cdot ||b_2||\sin\theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle between the vectors.  In this case, finding $\sin\theta$ is the most challenging part to this, but it can easily be found from the dot product as

$$
\sin\theta \;\; =\;\; \sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta} \;\; =\;\; \sqrt{1 - \left (\frac{b_1\cdot b_2}{||b_1||\cdot ||b_2||} \right )^2}.
$$